# Load native DLLs for third-party framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have Asp.Net App which needs a third-party framework (consisting of few managed and loads of native dlls) for a specific functionality.

I want to place all native dlls in another folder outside the bin folder of my web app.
Is there a way to tell the third-party managed dlls to load this native dlls from a specific directory? The managed framework itself provides no such function.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question may already have been answered:

[How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)

Or perhaps for a couple of other options:

[load a DLL reference from a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009047/load-a-dll-reference-from-a-different-folder)

Comment: I don't think these answers talk about native dll loading

Comment: I didn't notice that it was *only* the native dlls you wanted in another folder - thought it was that mix of managed/unmanaged.  Can't you just add the folder to the %PATH%?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710982/how-to-adjust-path-for-dynamically-loaded-native-dlls